# Wordpress taxonomy.php loop only showing 2 posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some real trouble with the below code in my `taxonomy.php` template in Wordpress. The query is working (i.e pulling posts only from within that custom taxonomy) but it is only displaying 2 posts (4 are in the taxonomy).

All my efforts to convert this into a standard loop using $args simply result in posts from all taxonomies being pulled into the page. I was hoping it is as simple as adding `posts_per_page => -1` but this just causes every post in the entire site to display.

As I understand it from the codex, taxonomy pages should pull the relevent posts by default, without a need for a loop?

Any help much appreciated!

**taxonomy.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main>    
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <figure>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>
            <figcaption>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>   
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<main> 

<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <figure>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>
            <figcaption>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>   
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Will you provide your custom taxonomy name, so that I can provide you code to show proper posts relevant to that taxonomy ?

Comment: Hi @laraib, I actually have 6 Taxonomies, each with multiple 'Terms'. The taxonomy page is used when a user clicks through from an Index page by clicking on a 'Term' - They should then be shown x number of posts form within that 'Term'. Make sense? My 6 taxonomies are: 'topics', 'places', 'dates', 'interviewee', 'period' and 'a-z'. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 6 different taxonomies then there will be 6 different template files to show those taxonomies appropriately. In your case your templates will be `taxonomy-topics.php` `taxonomy-places.php` `taxonomy-dates.php` `taxonomy-interviewee.php` `taxonomy-period.php` and `taxonomy-a-z.php`

In this way once these templates are created your templates will be showing appropriate posts. To achieve that you can use `posts_per_page` argument or you can visit this page for better understanding about fetching posts [WP_Query Codex Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) Hope that makes sense by now

Comment: Hello @laraib. Thanks for the answer, however, I'm not able to get this to work. I have create taxonomy-places.php to test, and I've updated the question with an updated piece of code that adds in the posts_per_page argument, but again I am left with every post in the website?

Comment: Ah, I've just realised that the reason only 2 posts were showing is because I had set 'Blog pages show at most' setting in Settings>Reading to 2. This is because I want this to apply on another section of the site. Can this be overidden?

Comment: that's great to hear that your problem has been solved. Yes you can, but by default it takes your main loop ... you can use WP_Query to get your posts in your taxonomies and so those will not effect your settings in other pages, and also make sure you reset your loop after usage.